# How can you increase computer's chances in a game of blackjack?

Tags: blackjack

Just wondering if I was to code a game of blackjack, how can I code it such that the chances of computer winning are always higher?

Answer (score 0):

How can you have a bigger chance of winning a chance game? By cheating!

The question is: **What kind of cheating are you willing to do?**

Maybe letting the computer know the card on top before deciding to take the next one?

Maybe introducing some bias in the way the cards are shuffled?